# If a property of an Object is not found (Obj Constructor) return value is Not undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

Consider a basic example where I am trying to ask for a property which doesn't exist in an object

**CASE-I:** (General Object)

```
var obj1 = {
  name: "Jack",
  age: 29
} 

console.log(obj1.city);
```

**Answer:** `undefined`

This means that if there is a property which is not present, it is rightly referred to as `undefined`.

**CASE-II:** (Object Constructor)

Now, I am going to do the same - first making a string which inherits from `String Constructor` which inherits from `Object Constructor`. The `__proto__` of Object-Constructor doesn't have a property named `__proto__` so the answer should be undefined. But rather (strangely) it returns `null`. Which is beyond understanding.

```
As far as I know, if the property of an Object is not found - its value should be `**undefined**` and not `**null**`.
```

[image]

Now, someone please help out in understanding - that after going up the `prototype chain` the concepts and implementations should remain the same. So, if the `__proto__` property of `Object Constructor` is not found, Why the answer should not be `undefined` but rather `null` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Javascript was designed, `null` is at the top of the prototype chain of *every* object. As the [specification says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-5), for the internal method `GetPrototypeOf`, its type signature is `( ) → Object | Null`, and it:

> Determine the object that provides inherited properties for this object. A null value indicates that there are no inherited properties.

Accessing the `__proto__` property of an object, or using `Object.getPrototypeOf` will invoke that internal method. The `__proto__` property *does exist* on most objects (so it doesn't return `undefined`), but the object it's called on is not guaranteed to have an internal prototype (and if it doesn't, that operation returns `null`).

See how `__proto__` is a getter/setter on `Object.prototype`:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__'));
```

That property will exist for any object that goes through `Object.prototype`, which most do. The getter may return `null`.

Note that if you create an object which does *not* inherit from `Object.prototype`, the `__proto__` property will not be in the prototype chain, and you'll get `undefined`:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj.__proto__);
```

Comment: So this means, that when we specially try to find `__proto__` property for any item (as most will have it) then that will trigger function `getPrototypeOf()` which has internally built in code which either returns `the prototype link` or `null` if it doesn't find it (1 of 2 options from within code). Right? (which will remove case of `undefined` as value was internally returned `null` from within logic)

Comment: Yes. You could define such a property yourself if you wanted: a getter which does `if (cond) return { someObj } else return null;`

Comment: Thanks! BTW, after asking question I was finding your id to ping you up for question. Found you were 3 min away, so anyways you were to come back and ans .. 
PS: :p